# JS Return Attribute From querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript, html, dom, selectors-api

I made a function that returns elements from the document.querySelectorAll() function. I tried to use this function to return the exact element with all the properties with it. I specifically want to return the tagName property.

```
<div id="#example"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function el(s){
        var newElement=document.querySelectorAll(s);
        return newElement;
    }
    alert(el("#example").tagName);
</script>
```

Comment: `alert(el("#example")[0].tagName);`

Answer (score 0):

`querySelectorAll` returns a `NodeList` of all the matching elements, even if there is only one. To get the element itself, use the `querySelector` function.

```
<div id="#example"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function el(s){
        var newElement=document.querySelector(s);
        return newElement;
    }
    alert(el("#example").tagName);
</script>
```

Comment: What would I do to return all elements matching the selector? For example: I have 6 div elements and I enter document.querySelectorAll("div")?

Comment: If you want a list of multiple elements, use querySelectorAll. From there, you can iterate through it to get a property of each element.